# $K$-Theory of finite dimensional Banach algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, noncommutative-geometry, banach-algebras

Is there  a finite dimensional  Banach algebra $A$ for which $K_{0}(A)$ is  a finite  group?

I  asked this question in MSE but I   received no answer

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624250/k-theory-of-finite-dimenional-banach-algebras

Comment: No, not even removing the word Banach, taking dimension over the ground field defines a surjection onto an infinite cyclic group.

Comment: @FernandoMuro   where are you using finite dimensionality?As we know there are algebras with finite k group?

Comment: I'm using that the algebra has finite dimension so that any f.g. projective module too, over the ground field.

Comment: @Fernando: I think you are implicitly assuming that your algebra has a unit.

Comment: @AlainValette Why so?

Comment: @Fermando: Because, for non-unital algebras $K_0(A)$ is defined as $\ker[K_0(\tilde{A})\rightarrow K_0(k)=\mathbb{Z}]$, where $\tilde{A}$ is the unitization of $A$, so you don't deal with f.g. projective modules, but with differences of modules having the same dimension.

Comment: @AlainValette   Prof  Valette, What is  $K_{0}(A)$  where  $A=$ is the  space of  strictly upper triangle matrices ?

Comment: If you allow non-unital algebras, it is easy to find a finite-dimensional algebra $A$ such that $K_0(A)$ is trivial (for instance, let $A=\mathbb{C}$ with the zero multiplication; then over $\tilde{A}=\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ all projective modules are free).  Whether $K_0(A)$ can be finite but nontrivial seems a lot harder.

Comment: @EricWofsey  thanks for your comment. do you think that the space of strictly upper triangle matrices gives finite non trivial k_ group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of  K$_0 (A)$ (where $A$ is a finite dimensional Banach algebra), that it be the kernel of $K_0(\tilde A) \to K_0(C) \cong Z$ leads immediately to it being a free abelian group, possibly zero (free on no generators); the latter occurs iff $A$ is nilpotent;  $\tilde A$ denotes the unitification.

Since $\tilde A$ is a finite dimensional unital algebra, $\overline{A}:= \tilde A/rad(\tilde A)$ is finite-dimensional semisimple, hence  $K_0(\overline A) $ is free finitely generated; since the radical of a finite dimensional algebra is nilpotent, $K_0(\tilde A) \cong K_0(\overline A) \cong Z^d$ for some $d$.

As $K_0(\tilde A) \to K_0(C) = Z$ is onto, $K_0(A)$ is free on $d-1$ generators. So $K_0(A)$ is either zero or torsion free. If $A$ is nilpotent, then $\tilde A$ has a unique maximal ideal, and then $d=1$. Conversely, if $d=1$, then $\overline  A = C$, forcing $\tilde A$ again to have a unique maximal (two-sided) ideal. For finite dimensional algebras (over any field), $\tilde A$ having unique maximal ideal is equivalent to $A$ being nilpotent (otherwise, $A$ would have a nontrivial idempotent, etc).

We only need that $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over some field for this to work, not a Banach algebra. The outcome is that $K_0(A)$ is finite iff it is zero iff $A$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Prof. Handelman  Thank you very  much for your answer.